# Plotting coordinates dynamically from XML file and refresh Markers only

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to plot markers on Google Maps with coordinates from XML file and below is my working script. My XML is dynamically updating. My goal is to plot coordinates my refreshing the Markers alone instead of whole page (currently achieving my using auto refresh in 5 seconds).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>WORK</title>
<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20;
  padding: 0;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;}    
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD5ATHIZrrP1XlFhEUVfCWZ2kc4oGIRbcw&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>
<script> 

var infowindow;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, 0.1275),

  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  downloadUrl("https://localhost/maps/data/markersfinal.xml", function(data) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Latitude")),
                                          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Longitude")));
      bounds.extend(latlng);
      var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("information"), latlng);
    }//finish loop
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }); //end downloadurl
}

function createMarker(information, latlng) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                           position: latlng,
                           icon: 'https://localhost/maps/images/marker1.jpg',
                           map: map
                           });
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
     if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
     infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: information});
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
   });
   return marker;
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()" >
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" > -->
</body>
```

This is my Downloadxml.js srript.

```
/**
* Returns an XMLHttp instance to use for asynchronous
* downloading. This method will never throw an exception, but will
* return NULL if the browser does not support XmlHttp for any reason.
* @return {XMLHttpRequest|Null}
*/
function createXmlHttpRequest() {
 try {
   if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined') {
     return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
   } else if (window["XMLHttpRequest"]) {
     return new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 } catch (e) {
   changeStatus(e);
 }
 return null;
};

/**
* This functions wraps XMLHttpRequest open/send function.
* It lets you specify a URL and will call the callback if
* it gets a status code of 200.
* @param {String} url The URL to retrieve
* @param {Function} callback The function to call once retrieved.
*/
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
 var status = -1;
 var request = createXmlHttpRequest();
 if (!request) {
   return false;
 }

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     try {
       status = request.status;
     } catch (e) {
       // Usually indicates request timed out in FF.
     }
     if (status == 200) {
       callback(request.responseXML, request.status);
       request.onreadystatechange = function() {};
     }
   }
 }
 request.open('GET', url, true);
 try {
   request.send(null);
 } catch (e) {
   changeStatus(e);
 }
};

/**
 * Parses the given XML string and returns the parsed document in a
 * DOM data structure. This function will return an empty DOM node if
 * XML parsing is not supported in this browser.
 * @param {string} str XML string.
 * @return {Element|Document} DOM.
 */
function xmlParse(str) {
  if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return createElement('div', null);
}

/**
 * Appends a JavaScript file to the page.
 * @param {string} url
 */
function downloadScript(url) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Here is my XML

```
<markers>
<marker information="109.127.8.242" Longitude="49.892010" Latitude="40.377670" />
<marker information="109.169.87.141" Longitude="-0.719860" Latitude="51.522790" />
<marker information="109.229.210.250" Longitude="24.105890" Latitude="56.946000" />
<marker information="109.229.36.65" Longitude="46.172170" Latitude="48.279550" />
<marker information="109.235.59.44" Longitude="12.095560" Latitude="49.015000" />
</markers>
```

Any suggestions if this is efficient way also refresh markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the call to `downloadUrl` into its own function.  Call that function from your `initialize` function.  Set a timeout to recursively call the function every 5 seconds.  Something like:

```js
var currentMarkers = [];

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, 0.1275)
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    getXml();
    var interval = window.setInterval(getXml, 5000);
}

function getXml() {
    for (var i = 0; i < currentMarkers.length; i++) {
        currentMarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    downloadUrl("https://localhost/maps/data/markersfinal.xml", function(data) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Latitude")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Longitude")));
            bounds.extend(latlng);
            var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("information"), latlng);
            currentMarkers.push(marker);
        } //finish loop
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }); //end downloadurl
}
```

Comment: Great. It works in this way. I initially thought ajax might be necessary.. This really solve my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: I also noted, the markers  only gets added up with the existing. On the first update of XML I had 10 inputs and on the second I had only 5, when the xml files refreshes i should have only got 5, instead I have 15. Am I missing something?

Comment: What you need to do is clear out the markers each time you call the function.  For that I've updated my answer to include a global variable, `currentMarkers`.  Add each marker into that array.  When you load the XML file, first remove each marker in that array from the map by doing `setMap(null)`.  Then as you loop over the new set of XML, add each new marker into the array, so you can delete them again easily 5 seconds later!

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way I import data from 2 xml files and display different markers on each?